# Paypal partner-referrals first party or third party integration

Tags: rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a marketplace platform with buyers and sellers, and sellers need to connect their Paypal account in order to receive payments from buyers. I'm using the partner-referrals endpoint to onboard sellers, but I'm not sure if the integration-type should be FIRST-PARTY or THIRD-PARTY for my use case.